# Laravel: extend a file from child folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i want to extend the topnav.blade.php located in the child folder.

view/pages/navfolder/topnav.blade.php <--i want to extend this file

view/pages/body.blade.php <--the file that will extend the topnav.blade.php

I tried this but fail:

```
@extends('navfolder.topnav')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `pages`, as in

```
@extends('pages.navfolder.topnav')
```